# GWT open a site/html?

Tags: gwt, menubar

In GWT MenuBar/MenuItem, how do you open a page/html file in another panel. Like when you set the target in

Though this should be in Java code...

Thanks in advance
Regards
Chrsitian

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by opening things in another panel. Do you mean in another tab or part of an HTML panel?

GWT has a [Window.open()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#open%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method that operates close to the javascript equivalent. By specifying the correct url, target name, and features, you can ask the browser to open something in the appropriate location.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. That might be it. Yes, I am trying to make a simple menu, like any other site with a navigation bar. Just like with  <A href=".." target="Home.html">. So new to GWT, i thought that in code you would do something like setting the target in the menuItem. I will try out Window.open()

Comment: Remember that it's extremely easy to add native javascript to GWT applications. If all else fails, find the JavaScript code you need online and wrap it...

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using the HTML Widget - and just called

HTMLWidget.setHTML(myResourceFile.getHTML());

From the MenuItem command execute()

Happy GWT'ing